# Stick figure AES: what does "I take each column and mix the bits in it" do?

Tags: aes

I've been reading [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) to help me understand how AES works. In [this](http://www.moserware.com/assets/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced/aes_act_3_scene_13_mix_columns_1100.png) picture it says:

> I take each column and mix the bits in it.

But then never explains *how* he mixes the bits. I've been searching for a while, but can find nothing about it. Can anyone explain what is happening in this step?

Comment: It is the Mix-Column steps. Did you read [Wikipedia AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and more detail [AES Mix column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns)?

Comment: @kelalaka ty I will read up on it :)

Comment: Also, the stick figure Guide, as said in the beginning, goes deeper and deeper implies more details further on the guide. Like this [one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51447/18298)

Comment: The [sixth to last panel](http://www.moserware.com/assets/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced/aes_act_4_scene_16_mix_columns_math_1100.png) of the cartoon describes it accurately, though not in my preferred way. It's tricky to explain if you've don't have much experience with finite fields.

Comment: @DanielShiu oh, guess I should have read a little farther, ty :)